# How to deal with non-existent (optional ) fields with F# and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, f#

I have managed to get data serialising into types quite easily.

```
let coll = db.GetCollection<PostDataItem>("postItems")
```

The problem I have is that when the schema changes, the data won't serialise properly into types because the data doesn't exist in the database.  I get the error:

```
MongoDB.Bson.BsonSerializationException: 'No matching creator found.'
```

I can't use the F# option type as it still requires a value - but is there a way with the standard .Net driver to serialise data where a field exists in the type but might not exist yet in the database.  I want it to default to null or None but don't want to have to change every record in the database.

My type definition looks like this:

```
type PostDataItem = {
    _id: BsonObjectId
    dateLodged: DateTime
    productCode: string
    productDescription: string
    clientReference: string
    manifestContract: string
    client: string
    quantity: string
    unitPrice: string
    gst: string
    total: string
    clientReference2: string
    weight: string
    reference1: string
    ticketNumber: string
    transactioncode: string
    invoiceExplanationField1: string
    invoiceExplanationField2: string
    invoiceExplanationField3: string
    invoiceExplanationField4: string
    invoiceExplanationField5: string
    invoiceExplanationField6: string
    orderNumberToCheck: string
    isUnique: Nullable<bool>
    expectedPrice: Nullable<decimal>
```

Ideas?

Comment: can you provide your type description?

Comment: @dododo  thanks - I have updated the description with the type description

Comment: Martin, I was updating my answer when you accepted it. Just want to make sure you saw the updated info.

Comment: @brianberns  Yes - I saw that - thank you! .  I added the [<CLIMutable>] as well.  It seems to be very slow learning the little issues with these.  I'm stuck on the next issue now where it is not updating - here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977840/issue-updating-a-field-that-doesnt-exist-in-mongodb-using-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`BsonDefaultValue`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/#default-values) attribute:

```
open MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes

type MyType =
    {
        [<BsonDefaultValue("MyDefaultValue")>]
        MyNewField : string
    }
```

(The default value must be a compile-time constant, so if you ever want a default value for an optional field, you have to use `null` instead of `None`.)

Alternatively, you can mark the entire type as `CLIMutable` and then missing fields will automatically be set to the natural default value based on their type:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type MyType =
    {
        MyNewField : string   // will automatically default to null
    }
```