# Issue Updating a field that doesn't exist in MongoDB using F#

Tags: mongodb, f#

I have written a save function

```
let saveRecord(record: PostDataItem, coll: IMongoCollection<PostDataItem>, orderNumberToCheck: string) = 
    let filterDefinition = Builders<PostDataItem>.Filter.Eq((fun d -> d._id), record._id)
    let  update = Builders<PostDataItem>.Update.Set((fun f -> f.orderNumberToCheck),orderNumberToCheck)
    let options = new UpdateOptions(IsUpsert=true)
    let result = coll.UpdateOne(filterDefinition, update, options)
    result
```

Unfortunately the result from MongoDB tells me that it found a match when trying to update, but it did not modify it ( matched=1,  modified=0 ).  The only unique thing about this is that the field "orderNumberToCheck"  doesn't actually exist prior to this - but I assumed that upsert would take care of that.  My type is below.

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type PostDataItem = {
    _id: BsonObjectId
    dateLodged: DateTime
    productCode: string
    productDescription: string
    clientReference: string
    manifestContract: string
    client: string
    quantity: string
    unitPrice: string
    gst: string
    total: string
    clientReference2: string
    weight: string
    reference1: string
    ticketNumber: string
    transactioncode: string
    invoiceExplanationField1: string
    invoiceExplanationField2: string
    invoiceExplanationField3: string
    invoiceExplanationField4: string
    invoiceExplanationField5: string
    invoiceExplanationField6: string
    [<BsonDefaultValue(null)>]
    orderNumberToCheck: string
    [<BsonDefaultValue(null)>]
    isUnique: Nullable<bool>
    [<BsonDefaultValue(null)>]
    expectedPrice: Nullable<decimal>
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I'm getting matched = 1 and modified = 1 in my test case. The only thing that looks a little suspicious in your code is that you've declared `_id` to be a `BsonObjectId` instead of an `ObjectId`. I don't even know what the difference is, but the examples I've seen use `ObjectId`.

Comment: However, when I try to update the same document a second time with the same value, I do get matched = 1 and modified = 0, but I think that's because the document has already been successfully updated. Are you sure that your document isn't being updated at all?

Comment: @brianberns Thank you. I rewrote it slightly using objected and it seems to be working.  I did notice that it was returning more than 1 record - I might have been mistaking the updated record.  thanks so much for your time.